# Background gradient disappears in IE9only SOMETIMES - Seems random

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

Man, I just can't figure this out. This is the damndest thing. In IE9, the background gradient seems to disappear, seemingly at random, depending on the width of my element.

Just to start off, here's a test link that you can view.

http://babackofficedev.radolo.com/TestButtons.aspx

What's also weird is that it doesn't happen in JS fidde:

http://jsfiddle.net/jmillspaysbills/n833q/

I think I've narrowed down the culprit, but I just can't figure out WHY this is happening. The issue seems to be the `background-size:` property. On my buttons with a gradient, I give it:  `background-size: 1px 175%`, then on hover: `background-size: 1px 100%` - this basically allows a smooth transition on chrome, firefox, etc. instead of an instant transition to a different gradient. Anyway, that all works fine.

I don't plan on changing this, because this is only effecting IE9, but I would love to know why it's happening so that I can try to figure out a workaround.

After some investigating, I've found that this only happens on certain widths. It just so happens that a word I was using: "role" was the perfect width for this to happen, which is how I figured this out.

Doing some testing, I've found that it happens at the following widths: 43px, 49px, 57px, 63px, 84px, 85px, 96px, 99px, 109px - That was as far as I got. I'm sure this happens above 109px, but I haven't tested above 110px.

I just don't get it. I can't seem to figure this out. Has anyone ever had this issue? Can anyone give me some input? It's driving me crazy.

Comment: I managed to get it to replicate the issue in JS Fiddle by just including the stylesheet. So it's definitely something in the stylesheet. I just can't figure out what it is!

http://jsfiddle.net/jmillspaysbills/n833q/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `1px` in `background-size` with `100%`. I don't know why that works, but it does.